# HttpClient with javascript

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to do a request and get a response from dynamic website, if I do this with normal Browser (like chrome) and see source code this show me all texts (no javascripts), but if I try to do wget or HttpClient I get response with javascripts and no texts.

Texts are dynamic, so how I can receive final source code (with texts)?

Please, if is not clear follow this steps:

1 - Go to http://www.stj.jus.br/webstj/processo/Justica/detalhe.asp?numreg=201201911000&pv=010000000000&tp=51

2 - Inspect elements and see source code from detalhe.asp

3 - Open terminal and use wget for get this page

now can you see the difference?

---- EDIT ----
If help, I trying to do this with HttpClient:

```
private static InputStream getPageSource(String url)  {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                String responseString = out.toString();
                //..more logic
                System.out.println(responseString);

                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return inputStream;
}
```

---- EDIT 2 ----
I got make this work putting one field in header: Referer

if I put this line before execute httpclient: get.setHeader("Referer", "http://www.stj.jus.br/webstj/processo/Justica/pagina_lista.asp"); everything works.. so, the problem now is:

How I get this parameter (Referer) from HttpClient automatically?

Comment: no - as expected, I get the identical response from both, though do note that there's a redirect involved. Perhaps whatever you're doing isn't following the redirect?

Comment: what command do you use for wget?

Comment: Straight-up wget with no parameters (on OS X 10.8.2): "wget http://www.stj.jus.br/webstj/processo/Justica/detalhe.asp?numreg=201201911000&pv=010000000000&tp=51"

Comment: have anyway can I pass files for you? I save the responses.. its big to paste here..

Comment: not really - how about putting them somewhere (dropbox, or whatever) and posting a link?

Comment: sure.. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50341801/reponse_browser.txt (BROWSER) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/50341801/response_wget.txt (WGET)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20287/discussion-between-greybeardedgeek-and-thamerhatem)

Answer (score 0):

Wget does not perform the role of a browser in that it is not interpreting and executing the javascript. It just asks for the resource at a particular URL and saves it to file. If you want to load the content as well then you will need to have access to a javascript engine. You may want to look at using [Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) which has a `JavascriptExecutor` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this, my problem here is with security, for security reason REFERER it's must be seted with "http://www.stj.jus.br/webstj/processo/Justica/pagina_lista.asp", so no problem with redirects or anything like this, just security.

Before I couldn't see this so I post the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching a similar issue, and the answer I keep coming across is to try http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/  It has a javascript engine embedded.  Depending on  your environment, the disadvantage of [Selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) is that it requires a browser be installed for it to interact with.